# Difficulties to insert code snippet inside y Joomla articles

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, codehighlighter

I am using Joomla 2.5.8 and JCE editor.

I am trying to use Code Highlight gesci Plugin to insert code snippet inside my article...

I do something like this:

```
{code}
INSTRUCTION 1;
INSTRUCTION 2;
INSTRUCTION 3; 
{/code}
```

The problem is thath: the final result is that it put my code inside the Code Highlight gesci plugin but theay are all on the same line, like this:

**INSTRUCTION 1;INSTRUCTION 2;INSTRUCTION 3;**

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your attention

Andrea

Comment: it's had for me to give an answer but could you try the <br/> ?

Comment: @Samitha Hewawasam: NO !!! If I have a class of 300 rows...I have to put 300 <br>...this is not a solution...

Comment: So u have to edit the plugin core .......

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre xml:php> - will highlight php formatted code
<pre xml:css lines="true"> - will highlight css formatted code, with line numbers.
```

one more thing. Since the `<pre>` tag shows contents as is, you may want to skip the new line after the `<pre>` tag and before the `</pre>` tag, like this:

```
<pre xml:php lines="true"><?php
// Here are a few lines of Joomla code
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
function getBaseURI() {
  return JURI::base();
}
?></pre>
```

[Read more](http://forums.modx.com/index.php/topic,3651.0.html)

[geshi-doc](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/geshi-doc.html)

Comment: mmm in Joomla articles seems don't work if I directly put this code inside the JCE or TinyMCE Editors...it work only if I put it directly in the HTML using an HTML editor such as CodeMirror but if I use a graphic editor like TinyMCE or JCE this is the final result: http://onofri.org/scorejava/index.php/corso-spring-mvc/11-pre-tag-in-graphic-editor

Comment: there is a option called Toggle editor, it will allow you to switch to HTML editor and paste the code and see.

Comment: Yes but when I come back to the WYSIWING editor...this one put its tag inside my code...

Comment: it's due to the fact that your plugin might not be installed correctly. try uninstalling and installing the extension again

Comment: I will try but...do you have ever tested this feture?

Comment: can you say me the exact name of the plugin that I have to use?

Comment: I read this tutorial but it don't speakc about WYSIWING editors...if I use code mirror work well !!!

Comment: i guess you will have to use it then

Comment: JCE and most other wysiwygs have built in filtering for security reasons.  You can disable some of it though editor settings (at least in tinyMCE you can).